# JSON parse error Swift 3

Tags: ios, json, swift, swift3

I have some error not undestand..
Well i send this code

```
JSONARRAY {
 JSON,
 JSONARRAY,
 JSONARRAY
}
```

Y have this but not working or not parse correct, no matter for while the two array is not adding anything

```
buscarEmpresa=[

"{\n  \"criterio\" : \"fru\",\n  \"tipo\" : \"0\",\n  \"idempresa\" : \"82\"\n}",
  [

  ],
  [

  ]
]
```

**The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.**

try this code..

```
let usuario = UsuarioSQL.getUsuario()!
var jArray: [AnyObject] = []

let jUsuario = NSMutableDictionary()
jUsuario.setValue((phBuscar.text?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines))!, forKey: "criterio")
jUsuario.setValue(String(describing: usuario.tipo_negocio), forKey: "tipo")
jUsuario.setValue(String(describing: usuario.id_server), forKey: "idempresa")
let jData = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: jUsuario, options: .prettyPrinted)
let jStr = NSString(data: jData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue) as! String
jArray.append(jStr as AnyObject)

let jaEmpresarial = NSMutableArray()
for i in receive_empresarial {
            let jEmpresarial = NSMutableDictionary()
            jEmpresarial.setValue(i, forKey: "empresarial")
            jaEmpresarial.add(jEmpresarial)
}
jArray.append(jaEmpresarial)

let jaPais = NSMutableArray()
for i in receive_paises {
      let jPais = NSMutableDictionary()
      jPais.setValue(i, forKey: "pais")
      jaPais.add(jPais)
 }
 jArray.append(jaPais)


 let post = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: jArray, options: .prettyPrinted)
 let jPost = NSString(data: post, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue) as! String

 let sesion = URLSession.shared
 let parameters = "buscarEmpresa=\(jPost)"
 print(parameters)
```

Comment: The above code itself seems to work fine. Where do you get the error? Also, it's better to use Swift arrays and dictionaries with type information than `NSArray` and `NSDictionary` in Swift code ...

Comment: Ok understand but some tutorial or example, please ?

Comment: See the update to my answer - I added some valid JSON based on the output from your code.

Answer (score 1):

The generated data is not valid JSON. That is probably why you get the error. You can verify this using a JSON validator, if you want to but depending on how you want to set things up, you might want this line of JSON:

```
{\n  \"criterio\" : \"some criteria\",\n  \"tipo\" : \"Type\",\n  \"idempresa\" : \"ID\"\n}
```

To be represented as key value pairs inside your JSON object, or as a value for a key. Something like this would be valid:

```
{
    "criterio": "some criteria",
    "tipo": "Type",
    "idempresa": "ID",
    "empresarial": [{
        "empresarial": 1
    }, {
        "empresarial": 2
    }, {
        "empresarial": 3
    }, {
        "empresarial": 4
    }],
    "pais": [{
        "pais": 10
    }, {
        "pais": 20
    }, {
        "pais": 30
    }]
}
```

You can use this [JSON validator](http://jsonlint.com/), to validate your own JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Well friends, I already solved it.. have changes

This not working for me, so make changes..

```
let usuario = UsuarioSQL.getUsuario()!
var jArray: [AnyObject] = []
    let jUsuario = NSMutableDictionary()
    jUsuario.setValue((phBuscar.text?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines))!, forKey: "criterio")
    jUsuario.setValue(String(describing: usuario.tipo_negocio), forKey: "tipo")
    jUsuario.setValue(String(describing: usuario.id_server), forKey: "idempresa")
    let jData = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: jUsuario, options: .prettyPrinted)
    let jStr = NSString(data: jData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue) as! String
    jArray.append(jStr as AnyObject)
```

This working fine for me

```
let usuario = UsuarioSQL.getUsuario()!
        var jArray: [AnyObject] = []
        let jUser: NSMutableDictionary = [
            "criterio" : String(describing: phBuscar.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)),
            "tipo" : String(usuario.tipo_negocio),
            "idempresa" : String(usuario.id_server)
        ]
        jArray.append(jUser)
```

And at the end I also made changes to my loops

```
let usuario = UsuarioSQL.getUsuario()!
    var jArray: [AnyObject] = []
    let jUser: NSMutableDictionary = [
        "criterio" : String(describing: phBuscar.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)),
        "tipo" : String(usuario.tipo_negocio),
        "idempresa" : String(usuario.id_server)
    ]
    jArray.append(jUser)

    let jaEmpresarial = NSMutableArray()
    for i in receive_empresarial {
        let jEmpresarial: NSMutableDictionary = [
            "empresarial" : i
        ]
        jaEmpresarial.add(jEmpresarial)
    }
    jArray.append(jaEmpresarial)

    let jaPais = NSMutableArray()
    for i in receive_paises {
        let jPais:NSMutableDictionary = [
            "pais" : i
        ]
        jaPais.add(jPais)
    }
    jArray.append(jaPais)

    let post = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: jArray, options: .prettyPrinted)
    let jPost = NSString(data: post, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue) as! String

    let sesion = URLSession.shared
    let parameters = "buscarEmpresa=\(jPost)"
    print(parameters)
```

**Thank you all for your answers i appreciate it a lot**